# If I've set the Cache-control response value as No-store; the browser shouldn't cache the resources right?

Tags: http, caching, cache-control

No matter many times I access the website, if the HTTP response Header has a value : No-store, the Browser(Chrome 71 or 75) should not cache the resources not matter how many times I try accessing it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the response header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)